Method not found set_ServerCertificateValidationCallback en consumo de WS Rest
Luego de migrar una KB de Genexus 17u9 a Genexus18u6, generando con .NetFramework el consumo de los WS Rest con protocolo HTTPS nos está devolviendo el siguiente error:
Method not found: 'Void System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.set_ServerCertificateValidationCallback(System.Func`5<System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage,System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2,System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain,System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors,Boolean>)'

El código para consumirlo es el siguiente:
&EnviaNotificacionInput.SDTNotificacionIN.EmpKey                = &EmpKey
&EnviaNotificacionInput.SDTNotificacionIN.ProCod                = &ProCod
&EnviaNotificacionInput.SDTNotificacionIN.PTNCod                = &PTNCod
&EnviaNotificacionInput.SDTNotificacionIN.MAILDestinatario      = &MailDestinatario.Trim()
&EnviaNotificacionInput.SDTNotificacionIN.MAILDestinatarioNombre = &NombreDestinatario.Trim()
&EnviaNotificacionInput.SDTNotificacionIN.MAILAsunto            = &Subject
&EnviaNotificacionInput.SDTNotificacionIN.MAILCuerpo            = &TextoEnvio

&HttpClient.AddHeader(!'Content-type',!'application/json')
&HttpClient.Host    = &MailHost
&HttpClient.BaseUrl = &BaseURL
&HttpClient.Secure  = 1
&HttpClient.AddString(&EnviaNotificacionInput.ToJson())
&HttpClient.Execute('POST', '/rest/EnviaNotificacion')
&JSON = &HttpClient.ToString()

Si el mismo código se ejecuta con la propiedad Protocol specification Unsecure(HTTP:) funciona correctamente.
¿Hay algo nuevo que haya que tener en cuenta o agregar en la configuración para consumir WS rest de forma segura en esta nueva versión?

Debes instalar Net Framework 4.8 en el servidor donde esta hosteada la aplicación.
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/es-es/download/dotnet-framework/net48
